# Getting the path of the original file folder not where it was included

Tags: php, function, include, require, filepath

I'm currently working on a PHP project in which i have a problem that I could not find a solution for.

here's how the project looks:

1. INC

   - functions.php
2. Main

   - index.php

In `functions.php` I have a perticular function that will give the current Working Path.
When I include in `index.php` `functions.php` like so

```
include '../INC/functions.php';
```

and then call my function `getCurrent()` it returns the path of INC not the path of where it was included and used? How can I get the path I am looking for?

Comment: What's wrong with using `__DIR__`?

Comment: well the function i'm using gives me a path like this one `http://localhost:8888/MyProject/Main/` and that's what i'm looking for, and since i use this a lot i made it a function @amenadiel

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]`. 
Imagine we have this file structure:

- folder1/index.php
- folder2/functions.php

**folder1/index.php:**

```
<?php
include('../folder2/functions.php');

getCurrent();
```

**folder2/functions.php**

```
<?php
function getCurrent(){
    echo 'Current file:'.$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
}
```

If you open folder1/index.php you'll get (for example):

> Current file:/folder1/index.php

Comment: First thing thank you for you answer, i appreciate you taking the time. But unfortunately the path needed for my project is not just that i want it to be like this : `http://localhost:8888/MyProject/Main/` i followed this tutorial to create getCurrent( ) function [link](https://wp-mix.com/php-absolute-path-document-root-base-url/)